# Using an array proxy to auto sort objects by property when item is pushed in

Tags: javascript

I would like to use a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to automatically sort an array of objects by a property when the set method is called.

The aim, is to get a sorted array when new item are pushed in the array.

What would be the best way to achieve it?

```
var myArray = new Proxy([], {
    set(target, prop, value) {
        target[prop] = value;

        // here i am trying to sort the array using lodash
        // but the problem is that the set method is called twice
        // and in final myArray is not sorted

        target = _.sortBy(target, function(o) {
            return o.id;
        });

        return true;
    }
});

var objList = [{id: 3, value: "A"}, {id: 2, value: "B"}, {id: 1, value: "C"}];
for (var i=0; i < objList.length; i++) {
    myArray.push(objList[i]);
}
console.log(myArray)
>>> [{id: 3, value: "A"}, {id: 2, value: "B"}, {id: 1, value: "C"}] //not sorted
```

**N.B.: I am using a proxy for other purposes (ex: custom `get` and others), so the sorting inside the proxy is required.**

Comment: you are trying to maintain a heap ?

Comment: can you paste the definition for `Proxy` too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is underscore sortBy makes a new copy of the array, but you want the original one modified. A simple vanilla javascript sort would fix it:

```
target.sort(function(a,b){return a.id - b.id})
```

Comment: Good! The sorting works now. However, the `set` method is called twice. Do you have an idea how I could prevent calling it twice? Maybe using `splice` ?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar its how setter mutation works. You are changing 2 things: First you are assigning a property to the array index, and by doing that you are modifying its length property, so method gets called again. You can check which one its doing by using console.log(prop == 'length')

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to give the array you want to insert to a new function which does insertion sort.
If you want this to work on all arrays you can add this function to Arrays prototype.
Here is a simple code example to get you started:

```
Array.prototype.insertSorted = function() {
  // do your insertion sort here.
  // this is the array you're inserting into

};
```